# Google Analytics not tracking events

Tags: google-analytics

I have the following code setup to track clicks on specific links on a specific page of our site:

```
<a href="http://www.mylink.com" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'MyCategory', 'click', 'MyLabel');">My Link Text</a>
```

These links go to a CGI script which logs users into a given service.  The login form also has our Google Analytics tracking code on it.

I have several links like this on my page with different labels.  Our CMS puts the Google Analytics universal tracking code below the content of our site.  I can't put this in the header.

I've tested it and checked in GA the next day, however it is showing nothing for event stats.

Is there something I'm missing.

Comment: You'll have to install something like Google Debugger to see if the hit is getting sent, or check in the dev console for the "collect" hit from that event. Also, make sure you have no filters filtering out that event from your view.

Comment: You'll also find it easier to track these things in Realtime reporting

Comment: The only filter I have is "include from our domain" which I limit to mysite.com.  The CGI form is within that domain.  I will try Google Debugger and see what it says.